# I'm using recursion and it is returning null in the below code

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6

According to me `hideLetters` should return an array. Can anyone please let me know what is wrong here? It is returning null.

I'm trying  to create a simplified version of the hangman game. Here, 
the default function gets 'str' input.

```
 import shuffle from '../../scripts/ShuffleArrayUtil';

        const checkHiddenCount = (arr) => {
          let count = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].hidden === true) {
              count += arr[i].count;
            }
          }
          return count;
        };

        const hideLetters = (gameArr, hiddenLetters) => {
          const gameArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameArr));
          if (checkHiddenCount(gameArray) >= hiddenLetters) {
            console.log('here', gameArray);
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameArray));
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
            if (gameArray[i].hidden === false) {
              gameArray[i].hidden = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          hideLetters(gameArray, hiddenLetters);


          return null;
        };

        export default (ansStr) => {
          let gameArr = [];
          const ansArr = ansStr.split('');
          const uniqAnsArr = [...new Set(ansArr)];
          const totalLetters = ansArr.length;
          const hiddenLetters = () => ((totalLetters % 2 === 0) ? (totalLetters / 2) : Math.floor(totalLetters / 2) + 1);
          for (let i = 0; i < uniqAnsArr.length; i++) {
            gameArr.push({
              letter: uniqAnsArr[i],
              count: ansArr.filter((x) => x === ansArr[i]).length,
              hidden: false,
            });
          }
          gameArr = shuffle(gameArr);
          console.log(gameArr);
          return hideLetters(gameArr, hiddenLetters());
        };
```

this is shuffle code

```
  export default (deck) => {
      const randomizedDeck = [];
      const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(deck));
      while (array.length !== 0) {
        const rIndex = Math.floor(array.length * Math.random());
        randomizedDeck.push(array[rIndex]);
        array.splice(rIndex, 1);
      }

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(randomizedDeck));
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'return null' statement in hideLetter?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? It's pretty suspicious that there's an explicit return of null and you're complaining it returns null...

Comment: I'musing ESLINT. If i don't put a return statement at the end of an arrow function it throws this warning. "Expected a return at the end of a arrow function". Also, even though I'm putting this statement. It should never reach there. since, i'm recursively calling function before return null. Also, at the end of the recursion it should return in IF condition that is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `hideLetters` there is a `return null` statement. Unless the condition `(checkHiddenCount(gameArray) >= hiddenLetters)` is `true` when you first call `hideLetters`, `hideLetters` will always return `null`.

Also notice that, when you recursively call the `hideLetters` function, you are not using its return value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i just used "return  hideLetters(gameArray, hiddenLetters);" It worked like a charm. Thanks for pointing this out.